# Punch needle tool settings do not match kit instructions

Tags: embroidery, tool-usage

I received a couple of needle punch kits from Joann's for Christmas, along with a 2.2 mm adjustable length punch needle (Boye), which was the recommended tool for the kits.

I was reading the instructions for the first kit (a fox's face) and it recommends using the #4 setting for the inner ears and whites of the eyes and the #8 setting for the rest of the face. My punch needle has settings from 0 to 5.

Is there a standard definition for #4 and #8? A needle length, perhaps, that I can use to convert to my needle's numbering system?

If not, how would I go about adjusting the settings? Would 2 and 4 work or 2 and 5?

Thanks!